# Counting substrings recursively

Tags: java, recursion, substring

I am struggling with an recursion problem that I do not know how to solve. Could you give a hint?

Example:
Given a string and a non-empty substring sub, compute recursively the number of times that sub appears in the string, without the sub strings overlapping.

```
strCount("catcowcat", "cat") → 2
strCount("catcowcat", "cow") → 1
strCount("catcowcat", "dog") → 0
```

This is the given method

```
public int strCount(String str, String sub) {
//...     
}
```

---

Edit (from comment) what i've tried :

```
public int strCount(String str, String sub) { 
   if(str == null || str.length() == 0 || str.indexOf(sub) == -1) 
       return 0; 

   if(str.indexOf(sub) != ) 
       str = str.replace(sub,""); 

   return 1+strCount(str,sub); 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: That looks like codingbat for me. Please practice by yourself and come back with a real question or problem.

Comment: Can you show what you tried and what went wrong with it? It's difficult to know exactly what kind of help you need based on the information supplied here - it would be a lot easier to provide appropriate guidance if we can see what you've tried so far. See also [mcve] for information on which code to include.

Comment: Off Topic.. please show us the code you tried to do first

Comment: This is what I tried but it did not work:

public int strCount(String str, String sub) {
  

  if(str == null || str.length() == 0 || str.indexOf(sub) == -1)
    return 0;
    
  if(str.indexOf(sub) !=  )
    str  = str.replace(sub,"");
    return 1+strCount(str,sub);
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way is pretty easy :

- if the `substring` is contained into the `String`, remove it **once**, and say you find it once `(return 1 + maybeThereIsMore`)
- else, say you did not find it and `return 0;`

---

```
public static int strCount(String str, String sub) {
    if (str.contains(sub)) {
        return 1 + strCount(str.replaceFirst(sub, ""), sub);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
strCount("catcowcat", "cat") → 1+strCount("cowcat", "cat") → 1+1+strCount("cow", "cat") → 2
strCount("catcowcat", "cow") → 1+strCount("catcat", "cow") → 1
strCount("catcowcat", "dog") → 0
```

---

Note : the method can be `static`, because it doesn't need any instance of your class , only the `parameters`

Comment: Thanks! Thats it. It did not work for me because I used "replace". I did not know there is a "replaceFirst".

Comment: @amaier sure, `replace()` will remove all occurence, you need to remove only one by one, think about voteup or accept the answer it's ok for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

We can count occurrence of substring in a string without updating the string (without replaceFirst() method). As strings are immutable in java so replaceFirst will not update the string it will create new string every time.

```
public static int strCount(String str, String sub) {
    return strCount(str, sub, 0);
}

public static int strCount(String str, String sub, int offset){
    int index ;
    if((index = str.indexOf(sub, offset))>=0){
        return strCount(str, sub, index+1)+1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hello :) this is my way of solving this problem!

```
public int strCount(String str, String sub) {


      if(str.length()==0)return 0;

      if(str.length()<sub.length())return 0;

      if(str.substring(0,sub.length()).equals(sub)) {

      return 1+strCount(str.substring(sub.length(),str.length()),sub);
      }

      else {
  return strCount(str.substring(1,str.length()),sub);
      }

}
```